# Ionic 2 Text doesnt Wrap in Select Component

Tags: html, text, ionic2, word-wrap

Below is my HTML-Code, but somehow the `text-wrap` doesn´t work in this Select Component. Does anybody have an idea?

```html
<ion-list>
  <h5 color="primary">
    Choose:
  </h5>

  <ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-select text-wrap class="selectWidth" okText="Ok" cancelText="Cancel" [selectOptions]="selectOptions" [(ngModel)]="Decision">
      <ion-option text-wrap selected="true" color="primary" value="vone" text-wrap>first first first first first</ion-option>
      <ion-option text-wrap color="primary" value="vtwo">second second second second second second second</ion-option>
      <ion-option text-wrap color="primary" value="vthree">third third third third third</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: have you tried setting `white-space: normal;` in `selectWidth` css class?

Comment: Yes, even with the !important tag...

Comment: Can you post the full code of how to get this to work? What is in the selectWidth class?

Comment: amin arghavani posted the correct answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

override this class in your .sass

```
.alert-radio-label {
    white-space: normal!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Do you know how to change the Color of the alert box which opens aswell? It seems to be another class then .alert-radio-label

Comment: use this: .alert-wrapper {
    background-color: purple!important;
}

Comment: brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: @Vasanth add to the page .scss file

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following to your `main.css` or `app.scss` should fix the problem:

```css
.alert-ios .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-line;}
.alert-md .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-line;}
.alert-wp .alert-radio-label{ white-space: pre-line;}
.select-text { white-space: pre-line;}
```